# How to tint icons of MediaStyle notification actions?

Tags: android, notifications

In my application I have a media notification (using the MediaStyle) and I need to have action icons with different tints. An example of what I want to achieve is the Spotify notification running on Android N:

[Spotify notification example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMFgM.png)

The Previous action icon doesn't have the same color than the other actions. I know I can tint all of them with NotificationCompat.Builder.setColor() method, but how can each action icon have a different color/tint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Starting from Lollipop, Android only use the alpha from drawables and apply its own color on them. The Spotify app use a black color, and with some alpha they can have a grey icon. So by tweaking the alpha of the used drawables, it's possible to have different tints on action icons.